# Simple MapReduce count in MongoDB not working

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to generate a statistical mode by using a simple count. The error I'm getting is

```
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet",
    "code" : 10075,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Here's my code.

```
var mapFunction = function(){ 

    emit(this.mode, 1);
};


var reduceFunction = function(key, value){

    Array.sum(value)

    return value;
};


db.runCommand(
{ 
    mapReduce : 'total_contractor_earnings_MR',
    map: mapFunction,
    reduce: reduceFunction,
    out: { replace: 'mapReduceContractorMode', db: 'large'}
}
);
```

Comment: Your reduce function is just returning the `value` passed into it, which will be an array of emitted results to reduce. This won't work. I suggest starting with some of the [Map/Reduce Examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) in the MongoDB manual to get a better idea of how to write your functions.

Comment: I have, obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: Notice you're adding Array.sum(value) but doing nothing with it. That's the sum you want to be returning from emit...

Answer (score 0):

Here you count a sum and do nothing with it.

```
Array.sum(value)
return value;
```

The thing you ment to write was:

```
return Array.sum(value);
```

The error occured because mongodb currently doesn't support returning an array from a reduce function